# How to clear typed characters from command line during user input

Tags: c, input, command-line, signals, buffer

In my program I have a while loop that continually gets input with `fgets`. I've set up a signal handler for SIGINT (Ctrl + C) so that the program will not return to the shell when Ctrl+C is entered, and continue in the while loop. However, when Ctrl+C is entered, there appears a bunch of `^C` characters in the next input prompt.

Is there a way that I can clear what's typed in the command line prompt? Perhaps by placing something in my signal handler?

```
// SIGINT signal handler
// is there something I can place here to clear what's typed (^c) into the command line?
void siginthandler(int sig){
    // do nothing (don't exit to shell)
} 

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    // change SIGINT disposition
    signal(SIGINT, siginthandler);

    While(1){
        fgets(input, 20, stdin);
        // some code...
    }

}
```